# Sending different variables through one switch statement

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, switch-statement

I have to create a slot machine for my first c++ class and I have to use the enumerated data type and a array for the reels.  My program currently pick all three reels random frames but for the life of me, I cannot think of a way to make it more compact. I have to keep all the reels values so I can create the win or loss outcome with if statements.  Is there a way to loop each variable through the same switch?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

enum frameType {PETROLEUM=1, COAL, NATURAL_GAS, URANIUM, GLOBAL_WARMING,NUCLEAR_DISASTER, DIRT};
enum outcomeType {PETROLEUM_WIN, COAL_WIN, NATURAL_GAS_WIN, URANIUM_WIN, LOSS, DRAW};

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  frameType frm1;


  int frameReel1[] =  {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7};
  int frameReel2[] =  {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7};
  int frameReel3[] =  {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7};

  int RandIndex1 = rand() % 25;
  int RandIndex2 = rand() % 25;
  int RandIndex3 = rand() % 25;

  int a = frameReel1[RandIndex1];
  int b = frameReel2[RandIndex2];
  int c = frameReel3[RandIndex3];

  switch (a)
  {
  case PETROLEUM:
    cout << "[petroleum]n";
    break;
  case COAL:
    cout << "[coal]";
    break;
  case NATURAL_GAS:
    cout << "[natural gas]";
    break;
  case URANIUM:
    cout << "[uranium]";
    break;
  case GLOBAL_WARMING:
    cout << "[global warming]";
    break;
  case NUCLEAR_DISASTER:
    cout << "[nuclear disaster]";
    break;
  case DIRT:
    cout << "[dirt]";
    break;
 }

switch (b)
{
case PETROLEUM:
  cout << "[petroleum]";
  break;
case COAL:
  cout << "[coal]";
  break;
case NATURAL_GAS:
  cout << "[natural gas]";
  break;
case URANIUM:
  cout << "[uranium]";
  break;
case GLOBAL_WARMING:
  cout << "[global warming]";
  break;
case NUCLEAR_DISASTER:
  cout << "[nuclear disaster]";
  break;
case DIRT:
  cout << "[dirt]";
  break;
}

switch (c)
{
case PETROLEUM:
  cout << "[petroleum]";
  break;
case COAL:
  cout << "[coal]\n";
  break;
case NATURAL_GAS:
  cout << "[natural gas]";
  break;
case URANIUM:
  cout << "[uranium]";
  break;
case GLOBAL_WARMING:
  cout << "[global warming]";
  break;
case NUCLEAR_DISASTER:
  cout << "[nuclear disaster]";
  break;
case DIRT:
  cout << "[dirt]";
  break;
}
} // end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one thing functions are very useful for - avoiding repeated code. This is your code, with the switch statement in a function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

enum frameType {PETROLEUM=1, COAL, NATURAL_GAS, URANIUM, GLOBAL_WARMING,NUCLEAR_DISASTER, DIRT};
enum outcomeType {PETROLEUM_WIN, COAL_WIN, NATURAL_GAS_WIN, URANIUM_WIN, LOSS, DRAW};


void printFrameType(int a)
{
    switch (a)
    {
    case PETROLEUM:
        cout << "[petroleum]n";
        break;
    case COAL:
        cout << "[coal]";
        break;
    case NATURAL_GAS:
        cout << "[natural gas]";
        break;
    case URANIUM:
        cout << "[uranium]";
        break;
    case GLOBAL_WARMING:
        cout << "[global warming]";
        break;
    case NUCLEAR_DISASTER:
        cout << "[nuclear disaster]";
        break;
    case DIRT:
        cout << "[dirt]";
        break;
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    frameType frm1;

    int frameReel1[] =  {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7};
    int frameReel2[] =  {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7};
    int frameReel3[] =  {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,7,7};

    int RandIndex1 = rand() % 25;
    int RandIndex2 = rand() % 25;
    int RandIndex3 = rand() % 25;

    int a = frameReel1[RandIndex1];
    int b = frameReel2[RandIndex2];
    int c = frameReel3[RandIndex3];

    printFrameType(a);
    printFrameType(b);
    printFrameType(c);
} // end main
```

There are other ways to improve this code, but you said this is your first C++ class, so I won't overwhelm you with new information. Since `frameReel1`, `frameReel2` and `frameReel3` are the same, why not just have one and call it `frameReel`?

Instead of using a function to shorten the code, you could also use a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    any code you put in here will run three times, so
    if you put the random choice and the switch statement
    in here, it will print 3 random frame types
}
```

You'll learn what `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` means later, but you can treat it as magic for now. Change 3 to a different number if you want it to run a different number of times.

Tony D's and LeonardBlunderbuss's answers are better, but involve more advanced concepts.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
int outcomes[3] = {frameReel1[RandIndex1], frameReel2[RandIndex2], frameReel3[RandIndex3]};
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  switch(outcomes[i])
    // Cases...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write re-usable supporting functions:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, frameType x)
{
    switch (a)
    {
      case PETROLEUM:        return os << "[petroleum]n";
      case COAL:             return os << "[coal]";
      case NATURAL_GAS:      return os << "[natural gas]";
      case URANIUM:          return os << "[uranium]";
      case GLOBAL_WARMING:   return os << "[global warming]";
      case NUCLEAR_DISASTER: return os << "[nuclear disaster]";
      case DIRT:             return os << "[dirt]";
      default:               return os << "<invalid>"; // or throw?
    }
}
```

Then:

```
frameType a = static_cast<frameType>(frameReel1[RandIndex1]);
...

std::cout << a << b << c;
```

(You should really be storing `frameType`s in `frameReel1`/`2`/`3`.